# How to get the accessibilty object for the main menu in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I need to set the accessibility attribute (`kAXFocusedAttribute`) of one element of the main menu. From this [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012630-CHAXUIElementhFunctions-DontLinkElementID_30), I can get the `AXUIElementRef` for the application by using `AXUIElementCreateApplication`, but I'm not sure how to get the accessibility object of the main menu (the menu on the top of the screen, a `NSMenu` object, or a `NSMenuItem` object for its element).

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!